# Getting error deployment due to two different OS configurations in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

We are facing the below issue on the bundle which is created by auto build. The build agent is configured with 32 bit server and our app server is with 64 bit server. Some of our node modules such as Appdynamics are not working with two different OS configurations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since some packages are not working with different OS configurations, you need to setup a new build agent.

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts)

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will create it now.Is there any other way to change any settings in azure servers/build servers ?Please let me know the possibilities.

Comment: I don't think you can change it.